# Locked property is not working in Windows Forms for Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

When I select `Locked property` to `true` for `Textbox` in `Windows Forms`. On runtime I will be able to type into that `Textbox`

So how to can I make it `readonly` without `disabled` effect or without using `ReadOnly` property of `Textbox`

Could someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats wrong with Readonly property?

Comment: Use a label instead.

Comment: The Locked property/feature is only for the designer. It only prevents you from moving or resizing the control in the designer, so you don't do so by accident. Setting ReadOnly to true is the way to do it at runtime, but you haven't explained why that is unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you @mike & all. I got my answer..

Answer (score 2):

The `Locked` property is a design-time only property.  It is useful to avoid accidental changes while you are designing the form.  When turned on, you see a little lock icon on the control and there's nothing you can do to accidentally change any of the control's properties.

But no, the control itself doesn't actually have that property.  It was added by the designer.  So it cannot have any effect at runtime.  There are other properties like that, such as `Modifiers` and `Language`.  Only useful for their side-effects at design-time.

Making a TextBox read-only at runtime is most easily implemented by setting its ReadOnly property to True.  If you want to do this at design-time then there's a very strong hint that you ought to use a Label instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }